# How to apply expression inside expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

So, I have property, which is an expression.

```
public Expression<Func<Profile, bool>> ManagerFilter { get; set; }
```

---

Next, I want to implement this filter, which is the expression above dynamically here:

```
var queryTest = applicantCacheRepo
            .Include(a=>a.Profile)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.ProfileEmployer)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Employer)
            .Include(a=>a.ProfileApplicationDetail)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.ApplicationStatusSysCodeUnique)
            .Include(a=>a.Person)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.PersonDetail)
            .Include(a=>a.JobSpecification)
            .ThenInclude(j=>j.JobSpecificationDetail)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a=>a.Profile == filters.ManagerFilter)
```

What I am trying to do here is to apply a filter for **Profile** in this query dynamically. The problem is that I do not know the exact property of **Profile** according to which it is going to be filtered.

---

**Question** is: how can I implement this filter dynamically here?

Comment: Instead of chaining it all, you could split it up into blocks which are "chained" inside `if` statements. Als long as you don't iterate/persist it, it will concat the expressions.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Hmm, what do you mean in particular? I did not get your idea

Comment: Next time post code. Images cannot be copied, analysed, searched.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for advice, I will definitely keep that in my mind

Comment: @NiyaziBabayev, replace images with text. And community will remove question downvotes.

Comment: Alright, wait a minute..

Comment: As a bonus for correction, you can replace chain of ThenInclude's of non collection navigation properties by just one include: `applicantCacheRepo.Include(a => a.Profile.ProfileEmployer.Employer)...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that only with help from third party libraries. I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then you can use your filter via `Invoke` extension:

```cs
var queryTest = await
   ...
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => filters.ManagerFilter.Invoke(a.Profile));
```