# EF Core 6 cannot translate a query when calling a function from lambda

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've updated my project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6. After the update, queries calling custom function throw error "The LINQ expression could not be translated". Here's a simple example:

```
Func<MyEntity, DateTime, bool> IsValid = (i, date) => i.BeginTime < date && (i.EndTime == null || i.EndTime > date);
var result = _dbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Where(i => IsValid(i, DateTime.Now)).ToList();
```

When the the function is inlined in the lambda, the query is completed successfully:

```
var result = _dbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Where(i => i.BeginTime < DateTime.Now && (i.EndTime == null || i.EndTime > DateTime.Now)).ToList();
```

The codebase relies quite heavily on such helper functions. Could someone explain, why this query does not work with the function, and is there some other workaround that inlining all those functions?

Comment: The error is correct. That function can't be translated - it never could. LINQ to entities works with *expressions*, not functions. The application already had this problem and EF Core 3 already generated lazy valuation warnings that were ignored. The existing code was loading the *entire table* in memory then filtering the loaded objects without the benefit of indexing. EF Core *5* finally converted the warning to an error

Comment: `The codebase relies quite heavily on such helper functions` that's bad, because the application is already running *very* slowly. This is neither a new change nor obscure knowledge. You *may* be able to get the query to work by changing `IsValid` to an expression, ie `Expression<Func<MyEntity, DateTime, bool>> IsValid = ...`. This can fail because the DbSet class implements IQueryable explicitly.

Comment: You may be able to use a library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder) to construct queries from expressions passed as parameters to some builder method. The other option is to call `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` and *then* filter. That's what your code was already doing after all - loading everything in memory, then filtering.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310636/how-to-apply-expression-inside-expression-dynamically/72310746#72310746) it shows how to apply LINQKit.

Comment: to complete all that was yet said, you may use an SQL profiler to check the generated sql, or use linqpad.